# How to change the network type of a network adapter to Private/Public from a Batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, networking, cmd, command-line

I would like to change the network type of my ethernet network adapter to private. Currently it is set to public. I need this for a setup script written in batch that is supposed to configure a Widnows VM including its networking automatically.

My understanding is you can change it using Powershell like this:

```
Set-NetConnectionProfile -Name "Ethernet" -NetworkCategory Private
```

But I'd like to do it using a Batch script.

Maybe it can be done using the `netsh` utility? I have been able to set a static IP address on my network adapter this way:

```
netsh int ip set address "Ethernet" static 192.168.99.2 255.255.255.0 192.168.99.1 1
```

As you can see in this screenshot, it is currently set to public, but I'd like to change it to private:
[image]

Comment: What is the reason you want to use batch instead of `powershell` do you have constraints of any sort, or are you adding this to an existing `batch-file`?

Comment: You can execute powershell commands from a batch file. `powershell -command Set-NetConnectionProfile -Name "Ethernet" -NetworkCategory Private`

Comment: I have an existing Batch file that has proven to run well on any Windows VM I've tried it on and I was planning to just add another command to it. I have trust issues with powershell because it's been causing lots of problems for me in the past. It never seemed to be a tool that just works out of the box on any Windows machine for me. Also, I wouldn't know how to translate my existing Batch file into a Powershell file.

Comment: It is trustworthy. I have massive powershell scripts monitoring 1000+ devices in a telco company and it is reliable. Simply add the `powershell` command to the batch file exactly as shown by @Squashman, it will perform the function within the batch-file.

Comment: I don't think you can draw such a conclusion by looking at the computers of one company. You probably use a small set of group policies and software on all of the devices, all patched regularly and all running Windows 10 x64 Enterprise. I have to deal with random users, each with their own completely random configuration.

Comment: Anyway the poweshell command didn't work. It complains the interface name is wrong. I may have found a beter solution though. Allegedly setting `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles\*\Category` to 2 would set it public. But the wildcard makes this extremely complicated beacuse it's a long random id. https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UgZv.png

Comment: @Forivin so change it to the correct interface name.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZca3.png